# Linq query for building a dictionary from a reg file

Tags: c#, linq, file-read

I'm building a simple dictionary from a reg file (export from Windows Regedit). The `.reg` file contains a key in square brackets, followed by zero or more lines of text, followed by a blank line.  This code will create the dictionary that I need:

```
var a = File.ReadLines("test.reg");

var dict = new Dictionary<String, List<String>>();
foreach (var key in a) {
    if (key.StartsWith("[HKEY")) {
        var iter = a.GetEnumerator();
        var value = new List<String>();
        do {
            iter.MoveNext();
            value.Add(iter.Current);
            } while (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(iter.Current) == false);
        dict.Add(key, value);
        }
    }
```

I feel like there is a cleaner (prettier?) way to do this in a single Linq statement (using a `group by`), but it's unclear to me how to implement the iteration of the value items into a list.  I suspect I could do the same `GetEnumerator` in a let statement but it seems like there should be a way to implement this without resorting to an explicit iterator.

Sample data:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.msu]
@="Microsoft.System.Update.1"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.MTS]
@="WMP11.AssocFile.M2TS"
"Content Type"="video/vnd.dlna.mpeg-tts"
"PerceivedType"="video"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.MTS\OpenWithProgIds]
"WMP11.AssocFile.M2TS"=hex(0):

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.MTS\ShellEx]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.MTS\ShellEx\{BB2E617C-0920-11D1-9A0B-00C04FC2D6C1}]
@="{9DBD2C50-62AD-11D0-B806-00C04FD706EC}"
```

**Update**
I'm sorry I need to be more specific.  The files am looking at around ~300MB so I took the approach I did to keep the memory footprint down.  I'd prefer an approach that doesn't require pulling the entire file into memory.

Comment: Can you please add a small sample of what the file looks like?

Comment: You can use `Aggregate` but it is not very different

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, you want to store the `[..]` as the key and everything else before the separating space as a value, correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use Regex:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<String, List<String>>();
var a = File.ReadAllText(@"test.reg");
var results = Regex.Matches(a, "(\\[[^\\]]+\\])([^\\[]+)\r\n\r\n", RegexOptions.Singleline);           
foreach (Match item in results)
{
    dict.Add(
        item.Groups[1].Value, 
        item.Groups[2].Value.Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList()
    );
}
```

I whipped this out real quick. You might be able to improve the regex pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `GetEnumerator` you can take advantage of `TakeWhile` and `Split` methods to break your list into smaller list (each sublist represents one key and its values)

```
var registryLines = File.ReadLines("test.reg");

Dictionary<string, List<string>> resultKeys = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

while (registryLines.Count() > 0)
{
    // Take the key and values into a single list
    var keyValues = registryLines.TakeWhile(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToList();

    // Adds a new entry to the dictionary using the first value as key and the rest of the list as value
    if (keyValues != null && keyValues.Count > 0)
        resultKeys.Add(keyValues[0], keyValues.Skip(1).ToList());

    // Jumps to the next registry (+1 to skip the blank line)
    registryLines = registryLines.Skip(keyValues.Count + 1);
}
```

---

EDIT based on your update

> Update I'm sorry I need to be more specific. The files am looking at
>   around ~300MB so I took the approach I did to keep the memory
>   footprint down. I'd prefer an approach that doesn't require pulling
>   the entire file into memory.

Well, if you can't read the whole file into memory, it makes no sense to me asking for a LINQ solution. Here is a sample of how you can do it reading line by line (still no need for `GetEnumerator`)

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> resultKeys = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("test.reg"))
{
    List<string> keyAndValues = new List<string>();
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = reader.ReadLine();

        // Adds key and values to a list until it finds a blank line
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
            keyAndValues.Add(line);
        else
        {
            // Adds a new entry to the dictionary using the first value as key and the rest of the list as value
            if (keyAndValues != null && keyAndValues.Count > 0)
                resultKeys.Add(keyAndValues[0], keyAndValues.Skip(1).ToList());

            // Starts a new Key collection
            keyAndValues = new List<string>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The linq enumerated File.ReadLines only reads a line at a time.  I don't understand why linq makes no sense for such a solution.  My original code is equivalent to your expanded code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a code like this - if you can use memory -:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
var result =
    Regex.Matches(lines, @"\[(?<key>HKEY[^]]+)\]\s+(?<value>[^[]+)")
        .OfType<Match>()
        .ToDictionary(k => k.Groups["key"], v => v.Groups["value"].ToString().Trim('\n', '\r', ' '));
```

[**C# Demo**](http://rextester.com/GNLV67007)
This will take 24.173 seconds for a file with more than 4 million lines - Size:~550MB - by using 1.2 GB memory.

---

**Edit :**
The best way is using `File.ReadAllLines` as it is lazy:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
var keyRegex = new Regex(@"\[(?<key>HKEY[^]]+)\]");

var currentKey = string.Empty;
var currentValue = string.Empty;
var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var match = keyRegex.Match(line);
    if (match.Length > 0)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentKey))
        {
            result.Add(currentKey, currentValue);
            currentValue = string.Empty;
        }

        currentKey = match.Groups["key"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        currentValue += line;
    }
}
```

This will take 17093 milliseconds for a file with 795180 lines.

Comment: Close, but I think you need `k => k.Groups["key"].Value, v => v.Groups["value"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(gc => gc.ToString().Trim('\n', '\r', ' ')).Where(c => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(c)).ToList()`.